# Recyclerview inside NestedScrollview scrollTo position not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

When I use RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView, then I use like `scrollTo()` fixed position, it's not working.

```
(rlv_brandWithLetter.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).scrollToPositionWithOffset(index, 0)
rlv_brandWithLetter.smoothScrollToPosition(index)
```

I read the source code of `NestedScrollView`,the method `scrollTo()` was executed.

```
@Override
public void scrollTo(int x, int y) {
    if (getChildCount() > 0) {
        View child = getChildAt(0);
        x = clamp(x, getWidth() - getPaddingRight() - getPaddingLeft(), child.getWidth());
        y = clamp(y, getHeight() - getPaddingBottom() - getPaddingTop(), child.getHeight());
        if (x != getScrollX() || y != getScrollY()) {
            super.scrollTo(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

But `x != getScrollX() || y != getScrollY()` always return `false`,this is the clue that I found.

Has anyone ever met this problem?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876952/nestedscrollview-coodinatorlayout-scrollby-scrollto-methods-do-nothing